# Como encontrar una línea de texto y devolver un valor con Powershell

Tags: powershell

estoy intentando aprender de manera autodidacta a utilizar Powershell.
Hoy intenté hacer una función que me buscase una línea de texto en un archivo txt y que me devolviese un valor dependiendo de si existe o no esa línea de documento de texto.
He probado de varias modos, pero no hay manera, no consigo solucionarlo.

```
$word = "Martes y Miércoles"
If ("C:/Users/Ángel/Desktop/Prueba.txt" -Contains $word)
{"Contiene estás palabras}
Else {
"No contiene estás palabras"
}
```

Esta función aparentemente funciona, pero no devuelve correctamente, siempre devuelve el else.

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En inglés https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41871147/find-specific-string-in-textfile

La respuesta que vale

```
$SEL = get-content C:/Users/Ángel/Desktop/Prueba.txt
if( $SEL -Contains $word )
{
   Write-Host 'Sí'
}
else
{
   Write-Host 'No'
}
```

Su problema es que está probando si el string "C:/Users/Ángel/Desktop/Prueba.txt" contiene $word y no lo que contiene el archivo C:/Users/Ángel/Desktop/Prueba.txt